# Shelf life of 1,4-Butanediol, colloquially known as BD or BDO

Tags: decomposition

1,4-Butanediol is a chemical cleaning solvent used for industrial purposes and a precursor of GHB. Companies now post the "official" shelf life as "2 years", but a 1997 publication by BASF said GBL had an "almost unlimited" shelf life if stored properly. Is there a reason 1,4-Butanediol would have a shorter shelf life than GBL? Would anyone know the real shelf-life if stored in sealed containers? How much would it chemically degrade after 10 or 20 years? Thanks!